# Example 3 of "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery" - Connect button not working

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to set up a xmpp client on my site so to get familiar I am following the examples of the book.  I have implemented example 3 by copying the code.  The only things that I changed were the strophe connection address to "http://localhost:5280/http-bind/" which is working and the script paths.  When I point to localhost/hello.html it loads as expected.  When I put my credentials in and press connect nothing happens though?  Would this be an error with the js?

Code is same as chapter 3 [here](https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp)

Edit: The problem with the connect button was that the strophe and flxhr js were not loaded correctly. So now the connect button works and calls the binded connect function as well as closes the dialog box. However, the connected and disconnected functions are not called so nothing happens after I press connect. What would cause that?

Comment: Do you actually have an XMPP server with BOSH running? Do you get a reply to the url with a browser?

Comment: Yes. I am running ejabberd with mod_http_bind enabled and http-bind enabled for port 5280. Http://localhost:5280/http-bind works

Comment: Alright, the problem with the connect button was that the strophe and flxhr js were not loaded correctly.  So now the connect button work and call the binded connect function as well as closes the dialog box.  However, the connected and disconnected functions are not called so nothing happens after I press connect.  What would cause that?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug Strophe.js issues is to watch the wire traffic. You can do this in two different ways.

1) Open the network panel of Firebug or in Chrome or Safari's developer tools. You can see all the posts and the responses from Strophe there. In this case, you'll want to see a few of these containing the initial XMPP setup plus authentication. If it's failing to connect at all, you'll usually just see a single POST that gets some error. If that's the case, post the error and perhaps I can diagnose it.

2) Define a logging function for Strophe and have it print out what it going on. This works well if you are establishing a BOSH session but otherwise having trouble. To do this:

```
connection.rawInput = function (data) { console.log(" IN: " + data); };
connection.rawOuput = function (data) { console.log("OUT: " + data); };
```

You could also have it append things into the DOM instead of using console.log to write to the JavaScript console.

For more debugging related information, you can do:

```
Strophe.log = function (lvl, msg) { console.log("LOG: " + msg); };
```

I believe that Chapter 4 covers some of these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that example and it worked for me. So if you didn't change the js code, the problem must be from the ejabberd server setup. Mostly it's your hostname setup in ejabberd.cfg. I'd try a couple of things:

1. In ejabberd.cfg file, make sure localhost is in this line:

   {hosts, ["localhost"]}.
2. If hostname is fine, increase your ejabberd log level to 5 and restart ejabberd. Post the ejabberd error message here and we can figure it out together.